# How to create multidimensional lists and loop widgets containing the lists value?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter & Dart and trying to build an App.

My Goal for now is to build a List (Array), but with an "index" to access it later. Afterwards I want to output it within a widget. Unfortunately I haven't found any tutorials or helpful ressources on the web.

1. Build a List which contains the date & days for an event. I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

   ```
   var events = [ {"day": "Monday", "date": "01.01.2019", "title": "Musical Event Austria"}, {"day": "Wednesday", "date", "01.01.2019", "title": "Musical Event 2"}];
   ```
2. Loop throught the list and output it within a widget

   ```
   new Container(decoration: const BoxDecoration(
             color: Color(0xFF0F1633),
   ),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           child: Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
               children: events.map((day, date, title) => new Text(title)).toList(),
             ),
           ),
         ),
   ```

So how may I build the list the right way and output it? What I want to output inside a Text Widget is actually the title, date and day...but really tried many ways to acchieve it, no way. :)))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may create a basic class for your need

```dart
class YourObject {
  final String title;
  final String day;
  final String date;

  YourObject({this.title, this.day, this.date});
}
```

create a `List` from that class/object

```
  List<YourObject> yourObjectList = [
    YourObject(day: "Monday", date: "01.01.2019", title: "Musical Event Austria"),
    YourObject(day: "Wednesday", date: "01.01.2019", title: "Musical Event 2"),
  ];
```

and you able to render `title` , `date` and `day` with like that or you can change the `Container` according to your needs/design

```
  return Column(
    children: yourObjectList.map((currentObject) {
      return Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(currentObject.title),
            Text(currentObject.day),
            Text(currentObject.date),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! Worked like a charme. :)))